# Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to crawl some mediafire links and facing a problem of too many redirects i have searched thoroughly on the internet but the problem i am facing is that some of the URLs don't get the "Too many redirects" error while some of them does Can you please help me as of what i am doing wrong ?

```
try{
        String url = "http://www.mediafire.com/file/110n342iorl685e/Guns-n%27-Roses_Paradise-City-TS_v1_2_DD_p.psarc";
        Document doc3 = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(0).get();
            for (Element sub3childrow : doc3.select("div.download_link")) {
                String link=sub3childrow.select("a").attr("href");
                System.out.println(link);
            }
    }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL http://www.mediafire.com/file/110n342iorl685e/Guns-n%2527-Roses_Paradise-City-TS_v1_2_DD_p.psarc
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.<init>(HttpConnection.java:623)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:656)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:628)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:249)
at custom_file_downloader.RedirectExample.main(RedirectExample.java:23)
```

I have tried to set followRedirects(true) and vice versa but it is not helping in anyway. Can you guide me in this regard ?

Comment: Why don't you check first URL is redirecting or not and then fetch correct url document ? For e.g refer this https://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-check-redirect-url/

Comment: i have tried it and come to know that it is visiting the same URL over and over again. Can you let me know why it is doing that because if you open the link in the browser it works fine @AbhishekPandey

Comment: Hey I'm not able to get you where exactly you getting the exception better paste your full code snippet and also share the exception stack trace. Note that for me with version 1.8.3 org.jsoup I'm able to see the body of doc object without any redirect exception for share URL.

Comment: I have updated the question you can have a look and i am using version 1.10.2 org.jsoup @AbhishekPandey

Comment: I've update my response in answer try with updated version it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with version **1.10.2** of org.jsoup jar. Quoting bug fix commit message.

> - Bugfix: In Jsoup.Connection, if a redirect contained a query string with %xx escapes, they would be double escaped
>     before the redirect was followed, leading to fetching an incorrect location.

Read this https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/826 for more. Later above issue was resolved in **1.10.3** version. So just update the version and try again.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

You will get the output with above dependency.